# How to divide rows (instead of columns) of a pandas dataframe by a list with repetition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and a list:

df:

```
|   | N_Friends | NFriends_Vacc |
|:-:|:---------:|:-------------:|
| 0 |     6     |       3       |
| 1 |     3     |       1       |
| 2 |     4     |       2       |
| 3 |     5     |       2       |
| 4 |     2     |       1       |
| 5 |     3     |       2       |
```

l:

```
l=[2,3]
```

I'd like to divide each row of the df by the list so that the first element is divided by 2, the second by 3, the third by 2 and so on. The output should look something like this:

df:

```
|   | N_Friends | NFriends_Vacc |
|:-:|:---------:|:-------------:|
| 0 |     3     |      1.5      |
| 1 |     1     |      0.33     |
| 2 |     2     |       1       |
| 3 |    1.66   |      0.66     |
| 4 |     1     |      0.5      |
| 5 |     1     |      0.66     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a series of same length as the df and divide the dataframe by that,

```
df.div(np.tile(l, len(df)//len(l)), axis = 'index').round(2)

    N_Friends   NFriends_Vacc
0   3.00        1.50
1   1.00        0.33
2   2.00        1.00
3   1.67        0.67
4   1.00        0.50
5   1.00        0.67
```

Comment: okay, so `np` has tile, will dig into this today (i just knew of cycle). :) Thanks.

Comment: @anky_91, Yes, tile and repeat are the ones I use the most :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df[:]=df.values/np.array(l)
df
Out[194]: 
   N_Friends  NFriends_Vacc
0        3.0       1.000000
1        1.5       0.333333
2        2.0       0.666667
3        2.5       0.666667
4        1.0       0.333333
5        1.5       0.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) for cycling the list for the length of a dataframe and then divide:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
print(df.div(list(islice(cycle(l), len(df))),axis=0))
```

---

```
   N_Friends  NFriends_Vacc
0   3.000000       1.500000
1   1.000000       0.333333
2   2.000000       1.000000
3   1.666667       0.666667
4   1.000000       0.500000
5   1.000000       0.666667
```